# Selecting protocol to transfer large (4GB) File through SSH port

Tags: ftp, scp

Attempts to transfer a file to a **remote (Windows 7) computer ** have failed:

- Teamviewer times-out
- WinSCP times-out

I am forced to re-start (vs. resuming) transferring the files. I have temporarily positioned the file on my linux router and opened the SSH port for WinSCP.  I can periodically access the remote (Windows 7) computer and WinSCP is available.  It would be nice if WinSCP had rsync built-in.

Is there a robust (can resume session disconnects) file transfer protocol or app  that will persistently reconnect until the transfer is completed (through SSH port 22).

- Update: SFTP retrieved via ipkg to Linux router: SFTP tested \ confirmed
- Update: Only the SCP connection over port 22 connected.

Comment: I'm guessing that if it times out, scp will return an error code, so you could easily write a bash while loop to keep calling it until it finishes without error.

Comment: `rsync` can transfer partial data over a flakey link given suitable flags

Comment: Pull it from a webserver using `wget` and the `-c` option.  But winscp's site states it can resume - https://winscp.net/eng/docs/resume#automatic

Comment: In detail it states: *"With SFTP and FTP protocols, when connection is broken, __WinSCP can automatically reconnect and resume__ the transfer. This can be configured on Endurance page of Preferences dialog."*

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this appears to refer to a server running Windows with client software that also runs only on Windows

Comment: The "server" is Linux router: not Windows.